# Problems managing dicts info in ansible

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to write in a jinja template an ansible registered variable. This variable seems to be a dict, I don't understand well why, because when I prompt it using debug module the system doesn't show it like a dict.

In the past, when I use python with REST API, I use the next line to make more readable a output:

```
json.dumps(print_data,sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Can I do something like this in ansible?

The current file generated from the template has the next format:

```
{'internal1': {'rx_packets': 4601675, 'name': 'internal1', 'rx_bytes': 556664119, 'tx_errors': 0, 'duplex': 1, 'ip': 'x.x.x.x', 'mask': 24, 'alias': '(V
LAN OT)', 'mac': '00:00:00:00:00:00', 'link': True, 'rx_errors': 0, 'tx_bytes': 432861677, 'tx_packets': 3227977, 'id': 'internal1', 'speed': 1000}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68831659/edit) your question with an [MCVE](/help/mcve). No one can guess what your input data looks like at start and what is the content of the template you use to output the file. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I am getting the input data from a host, I tried to solve it by using the copy module and then the nice_to_json option, but it didn't solve anything. Finally, I was able to solve it by the use of "nice_to_json" filter use in the jinja template

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I get the answer. I added the "nice_to_json" filter in the jinja2 template, this makes more readable for a human. As my brief experience has taught me, don't use this in the playbook, it doesn't work properly.